# Mobile Data blocked while getting/sending phone call and message

Tags: samsung, mobile-data, 9.0-pie

I have 2 sim cards in my phone Samsung J7 Pro. Whenever I used the packet data for internet using sim 2 and there's phone call or message coming in my internet got blocked. I used packet data because it's the only reliable internet connection I have right now. How to totally block all incoming call or messages to avoid my packet data blocked while using the internet?, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This all depend on your network provider. And also android operating system.
Generally in 2G network  when you get call, mobile data turn off. while in 3g you can use call and data simultaneously. This also depend on network strength and hardware.
while in 4G LTE, you can connect internet and make call.
So choose network which support data + voice.
kindly provide what is written near your network signal strength at the top of the screen E or 4G Volte.

Comment: mine is LTE but when I use the packet data from SIM 2, any call or messages from SIM 1 got my packet blocked.

Comment: Normally LTE can handle voice + data simultaneously. But it all depend on how your carrier provide network and network strength at your area.